# MS SQL Server: disable an index temporarily, but keep it updated for quick re-enable

Tags: sql-server, optimization, indexing, disable

I know about the `disable` option to `alter index`.  But this doesn't just disable its use for queries, it also deletes the index data, so if you re-enable it later that requires rebuilding the data from scratch.

Suppose I have an index that I believe is little used.  I've checked the performance counters in `sys.dm_db_index_usage_stats` and otherwise tried to make sure that dropping the index won't noticeably affect application performance.  Nonetheless, I could be wrong and I could make a mistake.  I'd prefer to just disable the index temporarily, so the query optimizer won't use it, but the index will still be maintained on disk when the table is written to.  After a few days I can take the second step and drop the index entirely.  If it turns out I was wrong, I can just re-enable the index instantly, without having to rebuild it from scratch.

To be clear -- suppose it's a big index on a big table, and I don't have an expensive edition of MSSQL that would let me do online index creation.  So I would like to avoid a long wait if and when I re-enable the index.

Is there some hack that will let me disable the index for queries, so I can make extra sure nothing is slowed down were it later to be dropped?  I'm using MSSQL 2016 but I would be interested in answers for later versions too.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there some hack that will let me disable the index for queries, so I can make extra sure nothing is slowed down were it later to be dropped?

No, there is no such functionality in SQL Server.  And Azure SQL Database implements [Automatic Index Management](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/automatic-tuning/automatic-tuning?view=sql-server-ver15#automatic-index-management) without such functionality, just by monitoring the index stats and missing indexs.